# Create PostgreSQL tables from CSV files

Tags: postgresql

I have 5 CSV files and would like to query those using PostgreSQL.

Is there an easy method to create a new PostgreSQL table from each of these CSV files?

I'm a beginner with PostgreSQL, I just installed v9.6 on my Windows machine.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Klin,
I have an error message saying I don't have the permission when I follow the'import' step from your message in the other post. The csv isn't on read only and doesn't seem to have any restrictions...

are you able to assist further?
Thanks

Comment: the error message is the following:
ERROR:  could not open file "C:\Users\Pierre\Desktop\sql-test-database\calls.csv" for reading: Permission denied
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "copy import from E'C:\\Users\\Pierre\\Desktop\\sql-test-database\\calls.csv'"
PL/pgSQL function import_csv(text,text) line 4 at EXECUTE

Comment: The folder with csv files has to be reachable by the user who owns Postgres, typically the user's name is `postgres`. In other words, o.s. user `postgres` must have read access to your csv files.

Comment: thank you very much Klin it works - it took me 10 hours to figure this out...